# How can I handle puppeteer to save pdf from a print dialog?

Tags: selenium, automation, headless-browser, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I have a print button and on clicking it, sends some request and opens up the print dialog. Now this is not coming directly from a URL and is not easy to decode.

Example print dialog

[image: Example print dialog]

Is there a way I can save this document as pdf using puppeteer?

Existing Code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({width: 1440, height: 2000});
  await page.goto(`https://www.southwest.com/air/check-in/review.html?confirmationNumber=${process.argv[2]}&passengerFirstName=${process.argv[3]}&passengerLastName=${process.argv[4]}`, {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
  });
  [ confirmationNumber, checkinButtonText ] = [ await page.$eval('.confirmation-number--code', el => el.innerHTML), await page.$eval('.actionable_primary.actionable_large-button', el => el.innerHTML) ]
  console.log(checkinButtonText);
  console.log(confirmationNumber);
  await page.click('.actionable_primary.actionable_large-button');
  // The below line makes a click on the button
  await page.click('.air-check-in-boarding-pass-options .boarding-pass-options--button-email, .air-check-in-boarding-pass-options .boarding-pass-options--button-print, .air-check-in-boarding-pass-options .boarding-pass-options--button-text');
  await browser.close();

})();
```

Comment: Please share your code and example of your result.

Comment: Please check the updated code. I don't think this will help you unless you have a previous southwest airlines ticket.

Comment: here is a exmmple
https://gist.github.com/glenhallworthreadify/d447e9d6b1fc9cb807b46f952236d4bc